# Как правильно настроить https для django на Nginx Proxy Manager?

Tags: django, nginx

Всем привет, подскажите почему django не видит https? У меня есть сертификат ssl, всё настроено, и на самом сайте всё работает на https, но когда в шаблоне получаешь request.get_scheme то результат http и запросы идут тоже с http, что это может быть?
Настроено всё с помощью NGINX Proxy Manager - docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.254
    restart: always
    ports:
      # Public HTTP Port:
      - '80:80'
      # Public HTTPS Port:
      - '443:443'
      # Admin Web Port:
      - '81:81'
    environment:
      # These are the settings to access your db
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "172.26.0.253"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "user"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx-proxy-manager:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.253
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "npm"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  testnet:
    external: true
```

Настройки nginx на самом сайте:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
 
    server_name testss.top;
 
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/testss;
    }
 
    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/testss;
    }
 
    location / {
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8008;
    }
}
```

Docker-compose сайта:

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: testss_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server.sh
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands
      - static_content:/var/www/testss
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.4
#    environment:
#      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testss.settings.${MODE}
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_content:/var/www/testss
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.5
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - backend  

networks:
  testnet:
    external: true

volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

Comment: Потому что в proxy_pass вы прописали конкретно протокол http. Если вы хотите, чтобы Django учитывал значение `X-Forwarded-Proto`, то пропишите настройку `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header

Comment: @andreymal мне нужно добавить это в настройки и в proxy_pass https?

Comment: proxy_pass https у вас c 99% вероятностью не заработает, не трогайте его

Comment: @andreymal не заработал, что нужно сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Прописать вышеупомяную настройку в Django

Comment: @andreymal сделал, мне не помогло, осталось http(

Comment: Вы уверены, что настройка применилась? Докер-образ с Django не забыли пересобрать и контейнер перезапустить?

Comment: @andreymal да, docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d

Comment: @andreymal или нужно ребилдить?

Comment: `listen 80` — а ну кстати да, вы же настроили работу nginx только на протокол http и он тоже не знает ни про какой https

Comment: Если у вас работают целых два nginx одновременно, то это наверное немножко зря, обычно достаточно одного nginx

Comment: @andreymal у меня настроен Nginx Proxy Manager для нескольких сайтов на одном сервере, он и пробрасывает запросы, на самом сайте есть https, но вот django видит только http

Comment: Ну в таком случае, видимо, нужно научить второй nginx считывать информацию об https из первого nginx, наверное как-то так `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;`

Comment: @andreymal не сработало(